# RadioButtonList Postback Issues

Tags: asp.net, postback, radiobuttonlist

Environment: ASP NET 2.0 - Production Server does not have Ajax Control Toolkit so no real Control toolkit to use here.

3 RadioButtons List:
List one loads, after postback, the item from list one is used to select a Lab value. 
Once a lab value is selected a 3rd radiobuttonlist will populate.  There are some textboxes but they are not shown in example.  The textboxes postback themselves on changes.  If both textboxes are
not empty, a record is created for the session.

Now if the 3rd radiobuttonlist is changed from the default a series of 3 hidden user controls appear which represent 3 levels of reasons for the change ( child/parent records in database ).

The problem I am having is when I select a different item on the radiobuttonlist the radiobutton 3 OnSelectedIndex is firing after my user controls fire.  My user controls need the value of the 3rd list to go to the database and get the correct set of records associated with the lab.

The problem is because the last radiobuttonlist is not processed until after the web controls loads, the code to mount the user controls never happens.

Here is the basic HTML code:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoLab" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdoLab_OnSelectedIndexChange">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBoxProcess" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBoxProcess" />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoPrimary" RepeatColumns="3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdoPrimary_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server"  ToolTip="Select Normal, Hypo or Hyper - Normal is default value." AutoPostBack="True" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Normal" Selected="true"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Hypo" />                                
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Hyper" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
     <asp:Panel ID="UpdLab" runat="server" Visible="true"  EnableViewState="true">
            <asp:Table ID="tblAdmin" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                      <asp:TableCell runat="server" id="tblCell1" Visible="false" CssClass="tdCell"  VerticalAlign="top"> 
                            <uc1:Lab ID="Lab1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" EnableTheming="true" />                                            
                      </asp:TableCell>
                      <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="tblCell2" Visible="false"  CssClass="tdCell" VerticalAlign="top">
                            <uc1:Lab ID="Lab2" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" EnableTheming="true" />
                       </asp:TableCell>
                       <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="tblCell3" Visible="false"   CssClass="tdCell" VerticalAlign="top">
                            <uc1:Lab ID="Lab3" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" EnableTheming="true" />
                       </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Here is the page behind:

```
protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreLoad(e);
        GetSessionVars();

        if (CommonUI.strTest((string)Session["rdoLabs"]) && CommonUI.strTest((string)Session["rdoPrimary"]) && Convert.ToString(hrdoLabs.Value) == (string)Session["rdoLabs"])
        {
            divLabLvl.Visible = true;
            // Get cboListItems from the web user controls...
            Session["ArrLstItems"] = "";
            ArrayList ArrLstItems = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList GetWuc = GetWUCS();

            for (int i = 0; i < GetWuc.Count; i++)
            {
                Lab wuc = (Lab)GetWuc[i];
                CheckBoxList cboItemList = (CheckBoxList)wuc.FindControl("cboItems");
                string cboItems = GetCboItemList(cboItemList);
                HiddenField hcboItems = (HiddenField)wuc.FindControl("hcboItems");
            }
            Session["ArrLstItems"] = (ArrayList)ArrLstItems;
        }

    } 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DbDataReader ddrGrp = rdoGroups();
            if (ddrGrp.HasRows)
            {
                rdoGroup.DataSource = ddrGrp;
                rdoGroup.DataBind();
            }
            ddrGrp.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            DbDataReader ddrLab = rdoUserLabs();
            if (ddrLab.HasRows)
            {
                rdoLabs.DataSource = ddrLab;
                rdoLabs.DataBind();
                if (CommonUI.strTest((string)Session["rdoLabs"]))
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["rdoLabs"]) > 0)
                    {
                        rdoLabs.SelectedValue = (string)Session["rdoLabs"];
                        SetLabCss();
                    }
                }
            }
            ddrLab.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void rdoGroup_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...do some stuff
    }

    protected void rdoLabs_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //... reload 
    }

    protected DbDataReader rdoGroups()
    {

        int group_type_id = GroupTypeId();
        Group grp = new Group();
        return grp.GetGroups(group_type_id);

    }

    protected DbDataReader rdoUserLabs()
    {
        RadioButtonList rdoGrp = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoGroup");
        int GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(rdoGrp.SelectedValue);
        LabAbnormalReasons lar = new LabAbnormalReasons();
        return lar.GetLabsList(GroupId);
    }

    protected void rdoPrimary_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Save"] = ((RadioButtonList)sender).ID;
        RadioButtonList rdoGroups = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoGroup");
        RadioButtonList rdoLabs = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoLabs");
        int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
        int DocId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DocId"]);
        SubmitLab_Data(arrLstItems, arrOthers);
    }

    protected void GetSessionVars()
    {

        RadioButtonList rdoGroup = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoGroup");
        RadioButtonList rdoPrimary = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoPrimary");
        RadioButtonList rdoLabs = (RadioButtonList)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "rdoLabs");

        if (rdoGroup.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Session["rdoGroup"] = (string)rdoGroup.SelectedValue;
        }
        if (rdoLabs.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Session["rdoLabs"] = (string)rdoLabs.SelectedValue;
        }
        if (rdoPrimary.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Session["rdoPrimary"] = (string)rdoPrimary.SelectedValue;

        }

    }
```

Here is example of user code:

THIS CODE NEVER FIRES BECAUSE the 3rd Button List data is not available here :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /////*
        //// *  lab & Primary have been selected... 
        //// */
        int lvl = SetLvlId();
        int par_id = GetParentLvl();
        Lab wuc = GetWuc(lvl);
        if (wuc != null)
        {
            if (CommonUI.strTest(Convert.ToString(Session["rdoLabs"])) && CommonUI.strTest(Convert.ToString(Session["rdoPrimary"]))) 
            { 
                    // data in data base for this user, lab, doc identifier...
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["rdoPrimary"]) > 0
                     {
                        // have user hdr data - see if item data is mapped...
                       // do some stuff here
                    }

            } 
        }
    }
```

I hope this is clear.  I've att

---***--- Since original posting: 
added simple javascript/OnDataBound 
 function Primary(object)
    {
       alert("Value Clicked :" + object);
    }

protected void rdoPrimary_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList rdlPrimary = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        foreach (ListItem li in rdlPrimary.Items)
        {
            li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Primary('" + li.Value + "')");
        }
    }

Comment: Have you tried to do your processing in the PreInit or Page_Init events to see if the behavior is the same or different?

Answer (score 0):

Store and retrieve the values you want to retain in SaveViewState and LoadViewState methods and see if that works for you? Also look to the earlier and later lifecycle events for handling the logic - Init and OnPreRender. This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I tried to add override on the LoadViewState. Nothing I put in that section is even hit when I debug.    I tried to add code to get the one specific user control and selected value.  Then I disabled all breakpoints in the program.  I then added a breakpoint on that set of lines of code.  When I step through the code, that neverfires?

Comment: My gut reaction is this is way over-complicated. Try and break it down into something simpler... build it in stages perhaps using cascading drop down lists instead.

Comment: Did you store the user's selections ViewState to begin?

Comment: I have two textboxes with data, and the 3rd control.  This represents the header record.  The 3rd control has 3 attributes:

Comment: The problem is the 3rd button, updates the user's header record and is supposed to drive the logic to show the user controls and drive what the user controls display. When I change that 3rd radiobuttonlist, it does fire the updates correct, but the page load of the controls occurs before I can get the change value of the control.  I have tried control unload to store the value to hidden field and that doesn't seem to work.  I could use a hidden field to drive this logic if I could get that done on unload.  But it seems the unload sees the initial value?

Comment: I usually solve this type of issue by moving things to Init and/or PreRender. RBL's don't hold their values so you are trying to deal with that on top of the life-cycle issues. I would re-think the UI and try to simplify it.

Comment: What am I moving to init or prerender?

Comment: I guess I'm struggling here because no matter what I do, the user interfacing of the logic is bound by the index change on the 3rd radiobuttonlist.  Knowing in the life cycle that is not processed until after onload seem difficult for me to figure out where I can capture the change to the control.

Comment: It's just another postback and I think it is doable but my choice would be to filter with DDLs. If you need something early put it in Init or PreInit... if you need to apply logic late, put it in PreRender. With judicious use of ViewState you should be able to do this.

Comment: Start again with cascading DDLs (just two to begin) and before you add the third, ask yourself the question: what if they change their mind and make a different selection in the last DDL ;-) http://bit.ly/hqJFCp

Comment: In "Buy a Car" sites, you will often see this, usually done "badly". My personal rule is to only let the user make a selection on the last selection control to appear. I'm hesitant to help you do this badly -start again with the UI and basic usability as if you're the one using it. Us programmers hate to hear this, but...

Comment: I have thought this layout through. I understand the users. The users select a Group they participate in.  Check.  The users select any relevant lab they need to fill out for a patien.  Check.  The users enter values that represent normal condition and patient values.  If the patient value is outside of the normal range either higher or lower, they select Hyper/Hypo in 3rd button.  Upon selection of Hyper/Hypo I wish the User control to display and run it's list of items.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the UI layout is correct. The student select group they are in. The student selects lab.  The student enters two text values and then decides a 3rd selection are those values normal, high or lo ( hyper/hypo).  That 3rd selection should show a list of questions; however those questions are tied to the selection of the 3rd item.  They can't even know that 3rd item unless they look at the two values they have entered.  So that control has to be the last control on the page prior to the selection.